# Why my server response status code is 200 instead of 200 ok?

Tags: java, http, spring-boot

I created a web application by `spring boot`.But i find the response status code is `200`

[image]

instead of `200 ok`

[image].

And i use `return new ResponseEntity<>("xx",HttpStatus.OK);`,the response code is also `200`.

Comment: Does it matter? Are you trying to parse out the word "OK"?

Comment: Status code for success is `200` and let us stick to it.

Comment: @cricket_007,Another application check the status code.And it requires the code must be `200 ok`

Comment: @MaxZoom,How to stick?

Comment: Why is the other application checking a string rather than a numeric response code?

Comment: One old app,can't change...

Comment: try deploying your application as `ROOT.war` instead of `app.war`

Comment: @ArunpandianM.I start the application use `java -jar`.The app builded by `spring boot`

Comment: @ArunpandianM Try it why?

Comment: There is no difference, 200 is same as 200 OK. 200 is code for machines, OK was just appended for human comprehension.

Answer (score 5):

The 'other application' is at fault. From [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

> 6.1.1 Status Code and Reason Phrase
>
> The Status-Code element is a 3-digit integer result code of the
>      attempt to understand and satisfy the request. These codes are fully
>      defined in section 10. The Reason-Phrase is intended to give a short
>      textual description of the Status-Code. *The Status-Code is intended
>      for use by automata* and the Reason-Phrase is intended for the human
>      user. The client is not required to examine or display the Reason-
>      Phrase.

Emphasis added. The 'other application' is an automaton, not a human user, and therefore should only be looking at the Status-Code.

Comment: Correct, except that you're citing an obsolete spec.

Comment: @JulianReschke The section I quoted is not obsolete.

Comment: The [obsoleting spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#History) is RFC 7230 where [section 3.1.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.2) says the same kind of thing, including this sentence: *A client SHOULD ignore the reason-phrase content.*